# How can I allow my NSFetchedResultsController to delete rows but not the user?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    if ([[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] == 0 ) {
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

This blocks my NSFetchedResultsController from calling didChangeObject with type NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject 
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type 
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(CustomScheduleTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                    atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView  deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView  deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
            [self.tableView  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] 
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
            break;      
        default:
            break;
    }
```

}

How can I fix this so that the user cannot swipe-delete rows in this section. But my program can from a background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method is only for allowing user interaction edits. Get rid of this method if you don't want that.